# Display formula result only if inputs are defined

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a simple spreadsheet, with one row of equations to get sums or differences. What I'm trying to do is enter an equation so that if only one part of the end equation is present, the field is left blank, but if two or more parts of the equation are present, the field is filled in with the end result of the equation.

Right now this is what the equations look like. As I said it is a very simple problem. I just don't know how to get it to do exactly what I want.

```
=[@QUANTITY]-[@Column2]+[@Column3]
```

Comment: Can you edit to show what the result is at the moment and what you want the result to be? I'm struggling to understand what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right this is what I think you are after.

Where column A is `@QUANTITY`, column B is `@Column2` and column C is `@Column3`;

```
  |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
1 | 34  | 2   | 5   | 27  |
2 | 32  | 5   | 5   |     |
3 | 43  |     | 3   |     |
4 | 53  | 43  | 3   |  7  |
```

If this is right then the forumla you want for row 1 is;

`=IF(B1="","",IF(C1="","",A1-(B1+C1)))`

I have written a breakdown of the formula below;

First check if cell B1 is empty, if it is then display an empty cell: `=IF(B1="","",`

However if cell B1 isn't empty then check cell C1. If it is empty then display and empty cell: `IF(C1="","",`

So far, if either of the cells are empty, then the result cell will be empty. However if both the cells have a value in, then we can do the math: `A1-(B1+C1)))`

Then just copy is down as many rows as you need.